# performance comparison in day wise group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's consider the following table.

**Table:**

```
ID
epoch_time_in_millis
counter
```

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch_time_in_millis/1000),"%Y-%m-%d") date,
SUM(counter) totalCount
FROM my_table
GROUP BY date
```

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT 
(epoch_time_in_millis DIV 86400000 ) * 86400000 ms,
SUM(counter) totalCount
FROM my_table
GROUP BY (epoch_time_in_millis DIV 86400000) * 86400000;
```

My question is: 
Will the above two queries show any performance difference?

If yes please let me understand why. 
If no let me understand why. :p

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check performance is on your hardware using your data.

But, MySQL implements `group by` using a file sort algorithm.  This algorithm does not generally take advantage of indexes, and especially not in your case.  Hence, the work for the two queries is going to be in processing the aggregation.

The other operations are trivial.  So, whether the engine does the calculation once or twice really isn't going to be relevant for the overall computation -- unless you have just a handful of rows.  And, in that case, performance isn't really an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's consider there are millions of rows in the table. Still the above two queries won't differ in performance? Since the second query involves multiplication and division operation I guessed that the two actually differ in the long run. Would you please clarify that? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @AnonymousOne . . . In general, the overhead for fetching and managing records in tertiary storage is much larger than a few arithmetic operations per query.  There are definitely cases where this is not the case (say, for user-defined functions or for functions on very long strings), but something of this nature is generally an over-optimization.

Comment: I've run these two queries separately on the same data set (~100K rows). The query #2 always outperforms query #1 on 10000 consecutive runs. The run time the query #1 takes is always > 2.5 times greater than the query #2 takes.

Comment: @AnonymousOne . . . In your environment, the date functions seem to be quite expensive.

Comment: [**Here**](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16503371/) you will find my server configuration. This is the server where I've run the experiment.